# Selecting with sqldf values greater than median of all values

Tags: sql, r

I am trying to find all the stock records where the yield is greater than the median for all stock using `sqldf` but I am getting this message.

I have tried using the actual number 2.39 and it works but I have not been successful substituting a variable to make it dynamic.  Maybe a sub-select would be better?

```
mYd <- median(df3$Yield, na.rm = TRUE)
df4 <- sqldf("SELECT a.* 
             FROM df3 a 
             WHERE (a.Yield > mYd)
             ;")
```

> Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : no such column: mYd

Comment: Preface sqldf with fn$ and then you can use string interpolation by prefacing variables to be inserted with the $ sign.  `fn$sqldf("SELECT a.* FROM df3 a WHERE (a.Yield > $mYd)")`  Note that the semicolon is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

The error is stemming from SQLdf's inability to find a column in `df3` called `mYd`.  It needs to find columns in the data frame for every corresponding column referenced in your query.  Try adding the `mYd` variable to your `df3` data frame as a column proper:

```
df3$mYd <- median(df3$Yield, na.rm=TRUE)
df4 <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM df3 WHERE Yield > mYd;")
```

Note that you don't really need to alias `df3` here since it is the only table in the query, and you aren't generating any computed columns.